# Writing string (REG_SZ) values to the registry in C++

Tags: c++, registry

I've got most of the code for writing a value to the windows registry, however when I change the path to a dummy key and value that I've set up for testing it fails.  My code is below:

```
    HKEY hKey;
    LPCTSTR sk = TEXT("SOFTWARE\TestSoftware");

    LONG openRes = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sk, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS , &hKey);

    if (openRes==ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Success opening key.");
    } else {
        printf("Error opening key.");
    }

    LPCTSTR value = TEXT("TestSoftwareKey");
    LPCTSTR data = "TestData\0";

    LONG setRes = RegSetValueEx (hKey, value, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)data, strlen(data)+1);

    if (setRes == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Success writing to Registry.");
    } else {
        printf("Error writing to Registry.");
    }

    LONG closeOut = RegCloseKey(hKey);

    if (closeOut == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Success closing key.");
    } else {
        printf("Error closing key.");
    }
```

All three tests yield error statuses.

The part that confuses me is that I was able to run this code when pointing it at other portions of the registry.  Any ideas?

thanks,
brian

Comment: Note that the `RegSetValueEx` function takes the string length in bytes (not characters) as its last argument. Therefore, you are better off using `StringCbLength` instead of `strlen`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I feel silly.  The solution is that need to properly escape the slash in the string as follows:

```
LPCTSTR sk = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\TestSoftware");
```

Hopefully someone finds this useful...

Comment: Or, starting with VC++ 2013: `LR"("SOFTWARE\TestSoftware")"` These are called _raw string literals_.

Answer (score 6):

```
HKEY OpenKey(HKEY hRootKey, char* strKey)
{
  HKEY hKey;
  LONG nError = RegOpenKeyEx(hRootKey, strKey, NULL, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);

  if (nError==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
  {
    cout << "Creating registry key: " << strKey << endl;
    nError = RegCreateKeyEx(hRootKey, strKey, NULL, NULL,     REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,NULL, &hKey, NULL);
  }

  if (nError)
    cout << "Error: " << nError << " Could not find or create " <<      strKey << endl;

  return hKey;
}

void SetintVal(HKEY hKey, LPCTSTR lpValue, DWORD data)
{
  LONG nError = RegSetValueEx(hKey, lpValue, NULL, REG_DWORD,   (LPBYTE)&data, sizeof(DWORD));

  if (nError)
      cout << "Error: " << nError << " Could not set registry value: " << (char*)lpValue << endl;
}

DWORD GetintVal(HKEY hKey, LPCTSTR lpValue)
{
  DWORD data;
  DWORD size = sizeof(data);
  DWORD type = REG_DWORD;
  LONG nError = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, lpValue, NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&data, &size);

  if (nError==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
     data = 0; 
  SetVal() is called.
  else if (nError)
    cout << "Error: " << nError << " Could not get registry value " << (char*)lpValue << endl;

  return data;
}

BOOL SetcharVal(HKEY Key,char* subkey,char* StringName,char* Stringdata)
{
  HKEY hKey = OpenKey(Key,subkey);

  LONG openRes = RegOpenKeyEx(Key, subkey, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS , &hKey);

  if (openRes==ERROR_SUCCESS) {

  } else {
    printf("Error opening key.");
  }

  LONG setRes = RegSetValueEx (hKey, StringName, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)Stringdata, strlen(Stringdata)+1);

  if (setRes == ERROR_SUCCESS) {

  } else {
    printf("Error writing to Registry.");
  }

  LONG closeOut = RegCloseKey(hKey);

  if (closeOut == ERROR_SUCCESS) {

  } else {
    printf("Error closing key.");
  }

}

char* GetCharVal(HKEY Key,char* subkey,char* StringName)
{
  DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;
  HKEY hKey = 0;
  char value[1024];
  DWORD value_length = 1024;
  RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,subkey,&hKey);
  RegQueryValueEx(hKey, StringName, NULL, &dwType, (LPBYTE)&value,     &value_length);
  RegCloseKey(hKey);
  return value;
}
```

I am using this code.

Comment: Please edit your previous code directly rather than posting a second answer to the question.

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of how your code solves the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

For `UNICODE` environment:

```
//Writing to registry
HKEY hKey;
LPCTSTR sk = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows");

LONG openRes = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sk, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);

if (openRes == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Success opening key.");
}
else {
    printf("Error opening key.");
}

LPCTSTR value = TEXT("Sample");
WCHAR path[80] = TEXT("C:\\samples\\app.exe");

LONG setRes = RegSetValueEx(hKey, value, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)path, sizeof(path));

if (setRes == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Success writing to Registry.");
}
else {
    printf("Error writing to Registry.");
}

LONG closeOut = RegCloseKey(hKey);

if (closeOut == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Success closing key.");
}
else {
    printf("Error closing key.");
}
```

Comment: Although `sizeof(path)` is definitely big enough, I believe what you want instead of `sizeof(path)` is `wcslen(path) * sizeof(WCHAR)`. This will be big enough for the entire string, too. In my code I pass `LPCWSTR i_lpStringValue` to my function, and use `wcslen(i_lpStringValue) * sizeof(wchar_t)` for the `cbData` argument to the `RegSetValueEx` function. It seems to save all the characters. Please feel free to correct me if I am misunderstanding something.