# Write to registry in Windows Vista

Tags: c++, windows-vista, registry, access-denied

I am trying to write to the registry from my application, but when I do I get access denied.  Of course, it works if i run the app as Administrator.  However, with my applcation, it is not initiated by the user.  It start automatically.

So, the question is, how do i read/write to my own registry key from the C++ app?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`

And check out this posts

[Vista + VB.NET - Access Denied while writing to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698193/vista-vb-net-access-denied-while-writing-to-hkeylocalmachine)

[Writing string (REG_SZ) values to the registry in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505024/writing-string-regsz-values-to-the-registry-in-c)

[How to read registry branch HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE in Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877851/how-to-read-registry-branch-hkeylocalmachine-in-vista)

Answer (score 0):

If your application starts automatically, could it be rewritten as a service? It would have system-level access to registry.

Comment: This depends upon the user account used to run the service. However, it is almost always the case.

Comment: Even if it doesn't run as SYSTEM, this might be a good idea. For instance, you can create a special non-interactive user account for the service with precisely the rights needed.

Answer (score 0):

If it's really *your* key, you control its security. The reason you need Admin rights is probably because you created the key with a DACL that refuses access to "normal" users. The most common way this happens is by inheriting a DACL from a parent key.