# Edit Windows 7 Registry in Python?

Tags: python, windows-7, registry, editing, access-denied

I have run into another problem with my current project. The program needs to values and keys periodically while running. Each time I attempt to edit the value, I get a code 5, Access Denied. How would I go about doing this so the values can be editied, but the user doesn't have to enter admin credentials to run the application?

I am using the _winreg module with Python 2.6 on Windows 7.

Comment: which keys are you trying to edit? what are the user's type? (limited user maybe?) which version of Win7 (Home/Pro/Ultimate)?

also, see this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992760/write-to-registry-in-windows-vista

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Yoni H ! Just write to HKEY_CURRENT_USER! DUH!!! Thanks again. Post this as an answer so I can accept it please! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit something that is writable only with administrative privileges, you just have to run under admin privileges. Everything else would be a giant security hole.